How to display data from Mongodb in ChartJS?
I have a pie chart and I need to display the data from the 'post' in it
Does anyone know how to do this?
const DoughnutChartComponent = (post) => {

const Ferum = isNaN(parseInt(post.title)) ? 0 : parseInt(post.title);
const Sulfur = isNaN(parseInt(post.text)) ? 0 : parseInt(post.text);
console.log('post.title:', post.title);
console.log('post.text:', post.text);
  console.log('Переменные', Ferum, Sulfur);
  const Other = 100-(Ferum + Sulfur);
      const data = {
          // labels: ['Fe, S, Other'],
          datasets: [{
            // label: ['Fe, S, Other'],
            data: [Ferum, Sulfur, Other],
            backgroundColor: [
              '#F7BA4E',
              '#D9D9D9',
              '#12191F',
            ],
            border: false,
            borderRadius : 3,
          },]
        };

      const options = {
          cutout: 60,
          responsive: true,
        };
      return <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />;
  };

My code seems to be working, but it outputs "undefined" instead of my values
Here's what the 'post' contains:

    {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6620ab8e815e0cddc8e0a7eb"
  },
  "username": "admin",
  "title": 54,
  "text": 23,
  "author": {
    "$oid": "6616156147d6e906caaf659d"
  },
  "comments": [],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-04-18T05:11:43.026Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-04-18T05:11:43.026Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}


there are a lot of posts, but I need to take data from the last one.
Chart rendering code:
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { DoughnutChartComponent as Doughnut } from "../components/Chart.jsx"
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {createPost} from '../../redux/features/post/postSlice.js'
export const OreComposition = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [image, setImage] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const submitHandler = () => {
    try {
      const data = new FormData()
            data.append('title', title)
            data.append('text', text)
            
            dispatch(createPost(data))
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='add-title h-screen flex justify-around items-center text-center ml-[246px]'>
      <div className='bg-[#313d44] rounded-lg py-3 px-10 w-50'>
        <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}
      className='mt-10 w-40 h-50 '>
        <h1 className='w-40 text-lg text-white text-center'>Ore composition</h1>
        <input
        value={image}
        onChange={e => setImage(e.target.value)}
        type="file"
        style={{display: 'none'}}/>
        <label className='text-xs text-[white] text-left'>
          Ferum:
          <input
          max="99"
          type="number"
          value={title}
          onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          placeholder='Ferum persentage'
          className='mt-1 text-white w-full rounded-lg bg-[#12191F] py-1 px-2'/>
        </label>
        <label className='text-xs text-white'>
          Sulfur:
          <input
          max="99"
          type="number"
          value={text}
          onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          placeholder='Sulfur persentage'
          className='mt-1 text-white w-full rounded-lg bg-[#12191F] py-1 px-2'/>
        </label>
        <div className='flex gap-8 justify-center mt-4'>
          <button
          onClick={submitHandler}
          className='bg-[#12191F] flex justify-center items-center text-xs text-white rounded-lg py-2 px-4'
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>

      </div>
      <div className="chart-box  h-80 w-80">
          <Doughnut />
        </div>
        </div>
  )
} 


Can you share what is the value for  post? And the code to render DoughnutChartComponent. Thanks.

@yong-shun, I edited the question and added the necessary information

You are not passing the title and text values to your Doughnut Component in your OreComposition component.
<Doughnut post={{ title: title, text: text }} />

Besides, React components treat the passed-in property(s) as an object. You should apply a deconstructor to obtain specific property as below:
export const DoughnutChartComponent = ({ post }) => {
  ...
};

Demo @ StackBlitz

Note: You should implement the validation to check the sum of both title and text values must be within 100. If you try the scenario as mentioned, even if the "Other" is a negative value, the doughnut chart will show the portion. You may refer to docs for the negative value.
